# Manually open a NSWindow from a Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

For an OSX app I have the UI in a storyboard, with the initial controller being a NSWindowController with a NSWindow attach to it. It works just fine when the window is opened automatically, but I can't get it to work manually, which is needed as the window should only open based on a human interaction.

```
NSStoryboard *storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

NSWindowController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialController];

NSWindowController *windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindow:vc.window];
[windowController showWindow:nil];
[windowController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[windowController.window makeMainWindow];

[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

In a different project it does seem to work when the view controller is a separate XIB file, but in this case, it doesn't. I do see an empty, rectangular window appear briefly, so something is happening. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

Here your windowController object is local to the selecor, it is getting deallocated when the selector which contains the code is returned.

Make `windowController`, a property of the object which contains this code.